# java generic array with iterator

Tags: java

I have a code like the following.

```
public class DefaultIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
private E[] array;
private int i = 0;

public DefaultIterator(E[] array) {
    this.array = array;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public E next() {
    return array[i++];
}

@Override
public void remove() {

}
```

}

```
// here is my execution.
    public Iterator<String> createNewIterator(Iterator<String>... generalIterators)    {
    return new DefaultIterator<Iterator<String>[]>(generalIterators);
}
```

I am getting the compilation error at the execution code. can somebody explain why it is failing and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the compilation error?  It will help if you can include it.

Comment: The constructor DefaultIterator<Iterator<String>[]>(Iterator<String>[]) is undefined

Comment: Mac, I am getting this. cannot convert from DefaultIterator<Iterator<String>> to Iterator<String>

Answer (score 3):

So the complaint is that none of the generic types match up between the field declaration, the constructor declaration, and the method declaration.

You want:

```
public Iterator<String> createNewIterator(String... generalIterators)    {
    return new DefaultIterator<String>(generalIterators);
}
```

Comment: I want 'Iterator<String>' for the return type.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is another one than expected! `DefaultIterator<Iterator<String>[]>` isn't compatible with `Iterator<String>` `Choose DefaultIterator<Iterator<String>[]>` as your return type, this should solve it.